# Computer Science SE coming up

Tags: discussion, community

Math.SE has about 400 questions tagged 'computer-science'. While most of them work well here, some questioners may appreciate more computer science flavor in answers, or may also have questions that are not ontopic on math.SE.

For those people (and others), a [Computer Science proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2) is well on its way to beta. Please consider supporting it if you are interested in computer science.

Note that the current description "Proposed Q&A site for Computer Science academicians." is not the community's choice. We are trying to have it changed to something like "For students, researchers and practitioners of computer science.", so that is what you should expect.

**Edit:** As of March 20th, [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com) is in public beta!

Comment: How is that different from the current cstheory site?

Comment: @Henning, see http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/3021/is-computer-science-a-duplicate-of-theoretical-computer-science

Comment: It seems that this proposal would make a lot of quite interesting mathematics off-topic on math.SE. How does one go about opposing these things?

Comment: @HenningMakholm How does a new site change the scope of math.SE? If you want to oppose, you can not do much more than voice your opinion. SE works that way; if there are enough people, you get the site. Your opinion might seem silly in the big picture, though; why oppose a CS site if only a tiny part of it overlaps with math.SE? That said, even if all CS related math would wander off, you can still subscribe to the corresponding tags on the new site.

Comment: @Raphael: Questions that are within the scope of another SE site routinely get closed and migrated to there. Having to follow two different sites would be a significant hassle for me.

Comment: @HenningMakholm There are always questions that can go to either site; we (have to) deal with that on cstheory.SE all the time. You already seem to be active on multiple SE sites, so what difference would one more make? I can recommend subscribing to tag-specific RSS feeds (if you use feeds at all, which I recommend as well) in order to improve signal/noise.

Comment: @HenningMakholm By the way, it seems as if you would make a great member for the new site, given your background.

Comment: I have posted another comment about this issue. I agree it would be unfortunate if good questions here were migrated blindly to the new site. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/overlap-with-new-cs-theory-lite-site

Comment: math.SE community control what gets migrated and what not. I (as questioner) would make the decision where to post based on what kind of answers I expect.