# Computer science questions being closed as off-topic

Tags: discussion, computer-science

There are now people [closing computer science questions as off-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130248/clarification-about-what-the-symbol-means).

We were [explicitly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/computer-science-se-coming-up) [promised](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/overlap-with-new-cs-theory-lite-site) that this wouldn't happen when the [CS site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) was created.

Could we stop that, please?

Comment: I think on your second link, you probably wanted to link to [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/overlap-with-new-cs-theory-lite-site) instead. Either way, it is not so clear that the question would have been on topic if what you call the "CS ghetto" would not exist.

Comment: @Michael: Why would it not be on topic? It asks for clarification of some notation used in a presentation of a mathematical theory the OP is trying to learn. Do you think that questions about notation should in general be unwanted here?

Comment: To me it is not clear whether the question of OP wasn't simply about MinML, which was the only context given.

Comment: @Henning, correct me if I'm wrong but this is about a syntax of a specific programming language (or am I wrong?) which I cannot for the life of me see as on topic, even if there were no cs.SE sites except SO itself.

Comment: I very much agree with Michael, there is no context to the question except a screenshot titled "*Abstract syntax of MinML*", if you wish to edit the question and add some context that will make it clear that this question is on-topic in a mathematics Q&A site then I'd be glad to vote to re-open.

Comment: @Michael: How is that different from asking what $d/dx$ means and giving a specific calculus textbook as the only context? MinML, it should be quite clear, is not something anyone studies for its own sake; it is merely a toy example for presenting some _general_ ideas in a mutually consistent form.

Comment: @Henning: The difference is that one can be pretty sure that the notation in a calculus textbook refers to mathematical notation and is not the ideosycraticism of a programming language. If you see an example in a calculus textbook about the growth rate of a population of *Pentalagus furnessi*, M.SE wouldn't be the right place to ask what *Pentalagus furnessi* means.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I guess I started the closure ball rolling, so I ought to comment here. I don't know what MinML is, but from context it appeared to be some computing language. I don't want to see questions here on what this or that symbol means in Fortran or Cobol (regardless of the existence of more suitable sites), and I took this to be that kind of question. Was I wrong?

Comment: @Michael: I'm equally pretty sure that the notation in this question refers to standard notation in the mathematical theory of types in programming language and is not an idiosyncrasy of the example language being used (except for the horrible typography in the slides, writing -> instead of $\to$).

Comment: @Gerry: I don't have any prior knowledge of "MinML", but it is extremely clear even from the limited information in the questions that is not a programming language anyone uses to _write programs_, but a toy _model_ of an idealized programming language that is being used to teach students how to reason mathematically about programming languages _in general_. Is your contention that simply because the mathematical theory the question is about can be applied to Fortran, questions about that mathematical theory should be asked on SO instead of here?

Comment: Moreover, it is very likely that "MinML" exists _only_ in the particular slide side the OP is quoting from. That kind of toy examples are throw-away constructions.

Comment: @Henning: Googling "MinML" shows that it does actually exist outside some example slide. See for example [here](http://freecode.com/projects/minml). The horrible typography was probably not horrible typography but correct code. People use *Scheme* mostly to illustrate ideas, but questions about Scheme commands would certainly be off-topic, and it is unclear whether OPs confusion wasn't on that level.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Oh, come on. The thing you link to is an XML parser written in Java. It has **nothing at all** to do with the question, except that it happens to have the same name as the OP professor used for his toy language.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I actually, don't how the MinML's relate, but I'm pretty sure nobody on MO should have to figure that out in order to understand the question. Do you really think the question was phrased well?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Are you arguing that the only questions that can be on-topic here are ones that one does not need to have _any_ knowledge about the traditions of their subject areas to understand? We would not have many questions left about _anything_, except perhaps basic arithmetic.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I take it there is no tradition of MinML. A perfectly acceptable version of the question would be this: "I read this |paper/book| on |mathematical topic in CS| and saw this symbol I'm not familiar. It looks like this: |Screenshot|." I don't think that question would have been closed. In a question about notation, providing context is especially important. There are certainly lots of uses of the arrow-symbol in mathematics.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: There _is_ a tradition of teaching type systems, and part of that tradition involves defining toy languages to show off one's concepts. Also, I fully agree that the question was badly asked, but here we are discussing whether it is _on topic_ for MSE or not. What is on topic or not is (or should be) orthogonal to how well one particular question about it is presented.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: In that case I presume the essential problem was not one of policy guidelines. To the untrained eye, the question looks like an off-topic coding question and that was why it was closed. I just gave my vote for reopening. It seems there is no actual danger that people consider type theory unfit for M.SE. Peace.

Answer (score 11):

> EDIT: The question has been reopened. I have cast my vote to close. If you think the question is off-topic...

While you raise a possibly valid concern, the example you choose is not right.

IMO, the MinML notation question is not on-topic on a Mathematics site.

I am thinking of it this way: Can a mathematics professor who has no knowledge of MinML answer this question without reading up about MinML? No.

The fact that this is the same notation used in Mathematics is irrelevant: you cannot possibly know that without understanding what MinML is about.

Given that MinML is not mainstream/a language which you expect a reasonable proportion of mathematicians to be familiar with(as you claim in a comment)/use, questions about MinML are very likely off-topic.

There are computer science questions which are on-topic and welcome here. That does not mean *all* of them are on-topic.

Comment: I agree with this answer, except that even if the question was "What does `bool` stand for in C?" it would still be off-topic. The fact that the language is obscure has nothing to do with the fact that questions about notation related to a computer programming language (in the broad sense of the term) is certainly off topic on math.SE.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I had mathematica type math-oriented languages in mind when I wrote that.

Comment: Well, now with the new mathematica.SE site running wild, I see no reason why Mathematica would be on-topic. I guess that you might be right and GAP/MATLAB/etc. would be on-topic here after all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yeah, not just mathematica :-)

Comment: I am not a mathematics professor, but I have no particular knowledge of MinML, and I can answer questions about it, under the assumption that it is fairly conventional toy language resembling the ML family. Mathematicians _who work in this area_ can reasonably be expected to be able to infer the details of such teaching examples, just like people can be expected to deal with minor notation variants and per-author idiosyncracies in every other mathematical area.

Comment: @Asaf, I agree that "what does `bool` stand for in C" would be off-topic, but this question is **nothing like that**. C is a particular language used in the real world -- C code is written on computers, in _stark contrast_ to the toy language in this post, which is written on whiteboards.

Comment: @Henning: Much like myself and Michael are arguing - that would have to require some context. I can assure you that if someone had posted a question "What does $\to$ mean?" it would generate a lot of negative buzz, probably closed and maybe get some +60 votes answer listing all the reasonable usage of $\to$ in mathematics. In the case you brought up, the minimal (and very vague!) context given was already creating a negative buzz and the question was closed without generating a +60 votes answer.

Comment: @Asaf: There is sufficient context for one familiar with the area to see what it is about. Are you really proposing that the definition of which areas of mathematics are welcome on MSE should depend on whether someone has posted an ill-written question about them? Or are you arguing that MSE should welcome only areas of mathematics in which it is _impossible_ to ask a question in a vague uninformative way?

Comment: @Henning: Right now I'm suggesting a good night sleep. This is at least what I intend to try. Arguing online can be tiresome and a good rest can do wonders! :-)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: What if the question was about the meaning of `::=`? Would that be on-topic? What about `;` (which is probably a statement delimiter)? You can guess whatever answer you want, but without some knowledge of MinML, you don't have an objective answer. All you have is an opinion/guess. If the question was, in Type Theory what does blah notation mean, then I agree it would be on-topic. The fact that the notation in MinML is borrowed from Mathematics, is irrelevant and does not make it on-topic. The context does matter.

Comment: @Aryabhata: The question _is_ about a notation in  type theory. The OP was just being a good boy and showing exactly where he found that notation, namely in a slide set that used this standard type theory notation in the context of a toy example lanaguage. The fact that details of _actual_ programming languages would be off-topic here is irrelevant and does not make the workings of mathematical examples of mathematical concepts off-topic here. The context does indeed matter, and you're persisting in ignoring it.\

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Sorry, IMO you are reading too much into the question and putting words into OP's mouth. OP/future askers might have no clue about type-theory and still be asking this question (and looking for answers for it on cs.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow). The question is about the syntax of a programming language, and that is what the context has been given as. For instance, I would not tag the question as type-theory. You are persisting in adding a context which is not there.

Comment: @Aryabhata: The question is about how to read a slide that defines the syntax of a (type system for a) toy programming languages. That is plain from the face of the slide quoted in the question, which by any reasonable definition is part of the "context". You are persisting in interpreting the question as something it isn't. Why would the OP has "no clue about type theory" if he is reading a set of slides _teaching that very subject_ and asking about how to understand one for the notations in that slide?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Where in the world did you get that OP is reading a set of slides teaching _type theory_? Personally speaking I have read about Haskell and ML without having anything to do with type theory, so I don't see your point at all. Sorry, I don't think we can agree on this and this conversation is just starting to get pointless, IMO. I will cast my vote to close if it is reopened. If there is not enough support in the community for closure again, so be it.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I get the fact that the OP is reading a set of slides typing theory from the fact that he is including an image of one of said slides in his question. The slide is **defining the syntax of types** in a toy system used to present how types work, ferchrissake!

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Again, that is you reading more than what is there. The slide is defining the abstract syntax of MinML. Even a slide on the C++ programming language will talk about syntax, and recursive data types. So? As I said, this conversation is getting pointless. I think we will have to stop wasting both our times. You raised a question on meta, and now let the community decide. I am done with this.

Comment: @Aryabhata: You are persisting in refusing to see what is plainly there, namely that the abstract syntax being defined is not for any real-world example but for a toy example designed to teach type theory _as a general subject_. The reason this is plain is that a language with only int, bool and function types would be absolutely, impossibly, cumbersome to write any real program. There is no possible world in which the types presented on that slide could be used to write programs on real computers that solve real problems. Its **only possible use** is to teach the mathematical theory of types.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: You seem to be arguing in favour of closing the question as too localized :-). Feel free to get OP to admit that the question is really about type theory rather than a syntax question about MinML, and add appropriate tags etc. Till then it is off-topic, IMO. Again, I see no point in continuing this conversation. I have tried to make my points. You should make yours (perhaps in another answer), and let the community vote and decide. Please don't be offended if I don't respond to further comments.

Comment: Too localized? Why on earth?

Comment: @Aryabhata: I agree with Henning. I have no working knowledge of any functional programming language whatsoever but I can see that the slide is not about the _syntax_ of a programming language but rather the _type system_ of a programming language.

Comment: @ZhenLin: All these arguments are getting to be pointless. Why not just ask OP what they really want, and stop imposing our own "between the lines" interpretations? You might write a brilliant answer with deep insights into type theory, but that is moot if OP does not understand, was asking a different question, and MinML is actually using the notation differently from what you think it should be using it as.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I think that's absurd: you're proposing to ask someone who doesn't know the meaning to a symbol to tell us what the symbol should mean!

Comment: @ZhenLin: No. I am not proposing that OP answer their own question, just that they provide more context: is it the syntax of the language they have a question about (which seems clear from what is written)? Or something else (which you seem to be reading the original question as)? Again, you are reading more than what was intended!

Comment: I voted to re-open not because I have strong opinions on whether that particular question is on-topic or not, but rather because the "off-topic" reason apparently sends a wrong signal, as the present thread indicates. To be honest, I find it an abysmally bad question (it's just a screen shot + "what's this?", after all) and I could live with either one of "too localized", "not constructive" or "not a real question", but the comments clearly indicated that it was the *topic* that led to closure and I disagree with that.

Comment: @T.b: I view it as a question about the syntax of a programming language. Like I asked before, suppose it was asking about the meaning of `::=`. Would one consider it on-topic? What about `; or |`? Where do we draw the line (if any)?

Comment: I'm upvoting the answerer and the OP because both raise valid points... I like meta questions like this because I can't decide who I think is right.

Comment: @Aryabhata: It's actually impossible to answer the question as stated. A symbol is just a symbol: it doesn't mean anything until semantics are given. The slide is simply making an inductive definition of ‘type’ in MinML without committing to any interpretation: it is just saying that there is a type `int`, a type `bool`, and if `t1` and `t2` are types, so is `t1 -> t2`. What does `->` mean? Nothing yet.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Well, if MinML has some standard/documentation, it is not impossible. All you need is to look up the _programming language_ reference...